# Google sheet formula for previous 7 day high

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-finance

Need a formula for previous 7 working day high for a share

```
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("nse:"&A2, "high", TODAY()-3.3), 2, 2)
```

Used the above formula but I need only workday formula.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("nse:"&A2, "high", TODAY()-9, TODAY())
```

[image: 0]